# Working with input type file AJAX/PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I have got this html/php in my index.php

```
if (isset($_POST['UploadMSub'])) {
    $fileP=$_FILES['Upload_f'];
    $fileP_name=$fileP['name'];
    $fileP_tmp=$fileP['tmp_name'];
    $fileP_size=$fileP['size'];
    $fileP_error=$fileP['error'];
    $fileP_extension=explode('.', $fileP_name);
    $fileP_extension=strtolower(end($fileP_extension));
    $allowed=array('jpg','png');
          if (in_array($fileP_extension, $allowed)) {
            if ($fileP_error===0) {
              if ($fileP_size<=2097152) {
                $fileP_new_name=uniqid().'.'.$fileP_extension;  
        }
      }
    }
    $_SESSION['fileP']=$fileP;
    $_SESSION['fileP_name']=$fileP_name;
    $_SESSION['fileP_tmp']=$fileP_tmp;
    $_SESSION['fileP_size']=$fileP_size;
    $_SESSION['fileP_error']=$fileP_error;
    $_SESSION['fileP_extension']=$fileP_extension;
    $_SESSION['fileP_new_name']=$fileP_new_name;
}

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class='SubmUploadFu'>
                  <textarea maxlength="400" type="text" class='Text' placeholder="New post"></textarea>
                  <input type="file" name="Upload_f" style="display:none;" id="Nameupload">
                  <label for="Nameupload" class='LabelCamerUp'>
                    <img src="../img/camera.png" class='CamerUp'>
                  </label>
                  <input type="submit" class="UploadMSub">
   </form>
```

And this ajax

```
$(".UploadMSub").click(function() {
        var text=$(".Text").val();
        var file=$("#Nameupload").val();            
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '../connect.php',
                data: "Text=" + text+"&&file="+file,
                success: function(data)
                {
                        alert(data);
                }
            });
                return false;
    });
```

connect.php

```
    if (isset($_GET['Text'])) {
        $Text=htmlspecialchars($_GET['Text'],ENT_QUOTES);
        $file=htmlspecialchars($_GET['file'],ENT_QUOTES);
        echo $Text." ".$_SESSION['fileP_new_name'];
}
```

But when i submit form it returns(alerts) 
"Undefine index ''fileP_new_name'"
Is there any other way of getting all information about file in my connect.php?

Comment: Fink u need to change fileP_new_name to fileP_name or define fileP_new_name properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem** is,

When you hit the submit button, the form doesn't get submitted, which means none of your session variables are set when you hit the submit button. Instead jQuery script runs straight away when you hit the submit button, and that's why you're getting this error,

> Undefine index: fileP_new_name

From your question,

> Is there any other way of getting all information about file in my connect.php?

So **the solution** is as follows. You have to change few things in your code, such as:

- Add a `name` attribute in your `<textarea>` element, like this:

  ```
  <textarea maxlength="400" name="new_post" class='Text' placeholder="New post"></textarea>
  ```
- Instead of returning `false` from your jQuery script, use [`preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method to prevent your form from being submitted in the first place, like this:

  ```
  $(".UploadMSub").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

      // your code
  });
  ```
- If you're uploading file through AJAX, use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object. But keep in mind that old browsers don't support FormData object. FormData support starts from the following desktop browsers versions: IE 10+, Firefox 4.0+, Chrome 7+, Safari 5+, Opera 12+.
- Set the following options, `processData: false` and `contentType: false` in your AJAX request. Refer [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to know what these do.

So your code should be like this:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class='SubmUploadFu'>
    <textarea maxlength="400" name="new_post" class='Text' placeholder="New post"></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="Upload_f" style="display:none;" id="Nameupload">
    <label for="Nameupload" class='LabelCamerUp'>
        <img src="../img/camera.png" class='CamerUp'>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="UploadMSub">
</form>
```

**jQuery/AJAX:**

```
$(".UploadMSub").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_data = new FormData($('form')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: '../connect.php',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,                         
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

And on **connect.php**, process your form data like this:

```
<?php

    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['Upload_f']['tmp_name']) && isset($_POST['new_post'])){
        // both file and text input is submitted

        $new_post = $_POST['new_post'];

        $fileP=$_FILES['Upload_f'];
        $fileP_name=$fileP['name'];
        $fileP_tmp=$fileP['tmp_name'];
        $fileP_size=$fileP['size'];
        $fileP_error=$fileP['error'];
        $fileP_extension=explode('.', $fileP_name);
        $fileP_extension=strtolower(end($fileP_extension));
        $allowed=array('jpg','png');
        if (in_array($fileP_extension, $allowed)){
            if ($fileP_error===0) {
                if ($fileP_size<=2097152){
                    $fileP_new_name=uniqid().'.'.$fileP_extension;  
                }
            }
        }

        // your code
        //echo $fileP_new_name;

    }   

?>
```

Comment: My Upload_f input is in index.php not connect.php so connect can not see that input

Comment: @TomOdell What do you mean *connect can not see that input*? Have you tested your application with these code snippets?

Comment: @TomOdell Yes, I know that *Upload_f* input is in *index.php* page. Here, you're actually submitting the form without reloading the page using AJAX.

Comment: Yes but u are not sending anything from Upload_f  to connect.php so it cannot know   $fileP=$_FILES['Upload_f'];

Comment: @TomOdell See this statement `var form_data = new FormData($('form')[0]);`, this will send both your file and text data to *connect.php* page. What issue are you facing now?

Comment: Well i copied all your code and now it says that undefined index:Upload_f In the if statement

Comment: @TomOdell Do you have any other form apart from this form in *index.php*?

Comment: Yes i have.Should i change FormData($('form')[0]); to form's class name?

Comment: @TomOdell Have you assigned this class `SubmUploadFu` to any other form element?

Comment: @TomOdell Okay, then change this statement `var form_data = new FormData($('form')[0]);` to `var form_data = new FormData($('.SubmUploadFu')[0]);`, and run your application again.